# Searching for an number in a list with strings, to return the number value

Tags: python, string, list, numbers

So I have a list of movies containing information on name, imdb rating and category as follows:

```
movies = [
{
    "name": "Usual Suspects",
    "imdb": 7.0,
    "category": "Thriller"
},
{
    "name": "Hitman",
    "imdb": 6.3,
    "category": "Action"
},
```

I'm trying to create a function to search in each item of the list for the number decimal i.e. the imdb rating, to compare it to a threshold value (>5.5)

The method I was thinking was to search for each item in this list when the number occurs and returning this value as I go through this list.

If I wanted to go about this method how should I tackle it? I've been looking at ways to return a value from lists but the methods I'm finding are for already known items returning an index...

Thanks for any help/ advice!

Comment: It looks like you're working with a JSON file, have you tried `pandas.read_json()`?

Comment: Hi Jeff, actually this is a direct code entry of movies I have in my script (not reading from a file) - I'm just practicing some Python on this for learning purposes. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each position in your list are a dictionary, to acess the 'imdb' you need to do this:

```py
# For each movie in the movies list
for movie in movies:
   # 'imdb' is a key of your dictionary
   if movie['imdb'] > 5.5: # The movie['imdb'] returns the value (the decimal number)
      return True # You can add to another data structure to store for example
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for movie in movies:
    imdb_score = movie['imdb']
    if imdb_score > 5.5:
        print(imdb_score)
```

Would this work for what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

```
movies = [
{
    "name": "Usual Suspects",
    "imdb": 7.0,
    "category": "Thriller"
},
{
    "name": "Hitman",
    "imdb": 6.3,
    "category": "Action"
}]
print([x['name'] for x in movies if x['imdb']>5.5])
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `movies` is a list of dictionaries, you could just loop through it if you don't have a massive dataset.

```
ls = []
for movie in movies:
    if movie['imdb'] > 5.5:
       ls.append(movie)
```